# Equal space of li in div with CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a full width `div` with multiple `li` in it, and I am trying to fit them in that parent div with equal space and force `LI` to appear from left to right, sometimes its breaking and showing next line, is it possible to make it filled in div and maintain it when its responsive?

This is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etqy3b2w/) example

Please suggest

```css
.msearch_cities {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.msearch_cities > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.msearch_cities > ul > li {
  border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
  color: #404040;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="msearch_cities">
  <ul>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Aligarh</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
    <li>Allahabad</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: By using flex you can get till [this](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/etqy3b2w/2/)

Comment: @VenuMadhav i think you did not get the reason of question. Op wants to have all li without extra white space while resizing the window.

Comment: Yes, exactly this is what I am looking for

Comment: Should i post as answer if you dont mind?

Comment: @Leothelion please post your answer as well, I would prefer CSS based solution :)

Comment: What does "with equal space" mean? Do you want equal widths? Do you want to justify the lines adding space in between? Do you want to justify lines making the elements grow?

Comment: I want to justify lines making the elements grow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you need is `flex`. You just have to update your code with given code

```
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: inline-flex;
```

so your **updated css** code will be

```
.msearch_cities > ul {
    font-size: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

And live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/etqy3b2w/7/)

To stretch out the elements use flex box. Flex-direction is used for maintaining them in a row and `justify-content` will set the space between elements.

To read more about flex box start [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: It works perfectly but one thing I noticed is the last row items, its having extra margin

Comment: That's the limitation of flex, i think. as justify content will stretch out items to maintain the width so if not sufficient child then it will behave like this. Same as when we do justify contet in paragraph then text text full size of box.

Comment: I think I would go with the CSS version and your answer seems to much better as compared to JS, as if the text in box becomes longer that currently it has then it would just overlap with other box.

Comment: @SanjeevK if you will have fix no of child then it will works perfect. Sorry but i can't give you much better then this. I will update if i will get any better solution. :)

Comment: thanks alot for the answer and I think this is the best answer for now!

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved using JQuery, Get the width of parent, define a minimum width of child and calculate each element width, like I did below

```
//Set the minimum width of child element
var minItemWid = 85;
//get the width of main container
var wrapWid = $(".msearch_cities").width();
//Get the number of items in a row and divide by minumum width of child above
var numOfItem = parseInt(wrapWid / minItemWid);
//Get the remaining space after the child element in a row
var itemWid = wrapWid % minItemWid;
//Remaining space added in to the child width
var remainSpce = itemWid / numOfItem;
//now assign the child width
$(".msearch_cities > ul > li").css("width",minItemWid + remainSpce);
```

Additionally, put the above code in in window.resize as well.

**EDIT** Here is a working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramkrishna18/etqy3b2w/5/)

You can set the minimum width in variable in js to match the container exactly

Comment: Sorry to say but op wants to have container full-fill rather then same size with gap which he is getting in his fiddle.